# How do I read SVN history in my solution and show in Visual Studio for user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, svn, solution

I want create information for no develop team from our svn history for solution and creat som page which can read all history in svn (log) for all pages.

Is it possible?

thank you for response.

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague, but I think that you are looking for `svn log` web view. And yes, it is possible. You can use a web-based Subversion client for this or try developing the client yourself. For example, VisualSVN Server has a modern web UI for viewing SVN repository logs. See the demo at https://demo-server.visualsvn.com/!/#asf/history/head/subversion/trunk